# nal_ref_idc value for the last frame in GOP when B frame is there for x264 encoding

Tags: encoding, x264

nal_ref_idc value during x264 encoding for each frame signifies that whether decoder has to remember or keep those frames in memory or not or in other words, whether those are reference pictures or not.

In general, I frame with nal_ref_idc value =3 and for P frames, the value = 2.

If one considers the GOP of this pattern, IPPPIPPP......

then why the last P also has a nonzero value of 2. I think it should be 0.

can anyone please tell why the last frame has nonzero nal value?

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn’t matter. Adding code to check what the NEXT frame will be is extra work. Especially for scene change detection. So just saying the frame MAY be referenced is less work and less code, and causes no extra work in the decoder because the IDR will flush all cached frames anyway.

Comment: can you tell me how long decoder will store the decoded frames? If all frames have nal_ref_idc value non-zero.

Comment: Depends on the profile. But the max is 16 frames. And everything is reset on IDR.

Comment: I have seen my H.264 encoded video stream consists I and P frames. so when the number of I and P frames exceeding 16 it will clear the buffer up. Right? For nal_ref_idc = 0 it will immediately delete the frame?

Comment: The decoder MAY delete the frame. More then likely it will just keep it and reuse the memory when it needs it.

Comment: the decoder is returning a pointer to the memory location for the decoded frame, if it deletes the frame for nal_ref_idc = 0 then the display module how it can display it?

Comment: It keeps a separate copy for itself. The one returned is for the user. Remember, not all decoders are software. stackoverflow is not a forum. If you want to talk about video, that’s great. But this not the correct venue.